# VBS add on not working in internet explorer (IE8) in Windows 7

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, registry, windows-7-x64

I have been trying to add a command to the IE command bar that will show a simple alert box on clicking (I'll be adding more functions to it later). For that I used this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753588(v=vs.85).aspx) to create a VBScript and added it to the registry (Both direct and through the wow6432 node).

The command works properly on windows 2003 systems that have IE-8 (IE 8.0.6001 to be specific) and it works on IE-10 with windows 7 systems as well.

But it does not work on Windows 7 systems that have IE 9 or IE-8.0.76 or later versions. The window simply refreshes on clicking the button instead of giving a popup.

Even after changing all the security settings to low and enabling everything it won't run the script. On adding the EXEC key in the registry it does run the script but outside the Internet Explorer which is as good as not running it.

I want to know if there is some change required for these particular versions of IE so that the same VBS can be executed by IE just the way it does in Win2003 systems or with IE10 in win7 systems.

Same was added in Wow6432Node as well.

Comment: The registry keys I added are: 

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions\{A6B13EE4-A974-11d2-8DB7-00C04FB6E8F6}]
@=""
"Default Visible"="Yes"
"CLSID"="{1FBA04EE-3024-11D2-8F1F-0000F87ABD16}"
"ButtonText"="Hello"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Folder\\IE\\Hello.ico"
"Script"="C:\\Program Files\\Folder\\IE\\hello.vbs"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. Basically the issue was with the security settings. In IE 9 or IE-8.0.76 or later versions, the setting “Allow active content to run in files on my computer” should be checked in the “Advance” tab of Internet options. By default it is not and that is what stops the script from running.

This resolves the above problem.